# how to fill dropdown in telerik grid databound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, telerik, dotnetnuke

i have a telerik grid and use GridTemplateColumn as bellow

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Status" ReadOnly="true" UniqueName="colStatus" HeaderText="Status">  
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpstatus" runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>                                    
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

then i fill dropdown and label in ItemDataBound event :

```
protected void grdList_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{

            if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
                {
                    GridEditableItem editItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
                    var info = (ProductViewInfo)e.Item.DataItem;
                    DropDownList drpstatus = (DropDownList)editItem["colStatus"].FindControl("drpstatus");
                    var cntType = new ProductTypeController();
                    var lst = cntType.GetStatusList(PortalId, enumTypes.MainGroup);
                    drpstatus.DataSource = lst;
                    drpstatus.DataTextField = "Caption";
                    drpstatus.DataValueField = "StatusID";
                    drpstatus.DataBind();
                    drpstatus.SelectedValue = info.Status.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    var item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
                    var info = (ProductViewInfo)item.DataItem;

                    Label lblStatus = (Label)item["colStatus"].FindControl("lblStatus"); 
                    lblStatus.Text = info.StatusCaption;
                }
            }
 }
```

but my drop down does not fill! "e.Item.IsInEditMode" always returns false. should i add anything  else in order to fill dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem related to `ReadOnly="true"`
try to remove it

Comment: i remove it, still empty dropdown!

Comment: e.Item.IsInEditMode" returns false again??