# How to bind enum to telerik:RadGrid in ASP WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, telerik

Can you help me with two way binding: displaying enum values in table and choosing an option in edit mode from drop-down list?

```
<telerik:RadGrid>
    <MasterTableView>
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataField="MyEnumProperty" />
    </Columns>
<telerik:RadGrid>
```

With code above it does not display current value in the table nor populate drop-down list (it is empty).

Comment: Show your datasource and how you set it.

Comment: Please paste your C# code, you should pass it as a data source not simply as `DataField`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but as I got it working...
I went with method 2 from @Balaji, but have to make several improvements, so to make it all in one place:

View part:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="My header" UniqueName="uniqueName" AllowFiltering="true">
<ItemTemplate>
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyEnumProperty")%>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <telerik:RadComboBox name="myComboId" Id="myComboId" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Code behind:

```
var dataItem = e.Item as GridEditFormItem;

if (dataItem != null)
{
    {
        var comboBox = dataItem.FindControl("myComboId") as RadComboBox;

        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            var value = DataBinder.Eval(dataItem.DataItem, "MyEnumProperty").ToString();
            comboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumProperty));
            comboBox.DataBind();
            var selectedItem = comboBox.FindItemByText(value);
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = selectedItem.Index;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

**Method 1 : (you cannot do this for your case)**

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="grid">
            <MasterTableView>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridDropDownColumn UniqueName="drpColumn" DataField="MyEnumProperty" />
            </Columns>
        <telerik:RadGrid>
```

**Method 2 :**

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="dropdown" UniqueName="drpColumn" AllowFiltering="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "textTodisplay")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlForEdit" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Considering, on the top of methods inside class you have enums

```
 enum ddlElements
 {
   a, b, c, d
 };
```

Then in `GridItemDataBound` event

```
protected void grid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
    GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
    GridEditableItem editItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode) // Only when the grid is in EDIT MODE
    {
RadComboBoxItem selectedItem = new RadComboBoxItem(); 
RadComboBox editor= (RadComboBox)grid["drpColumn"].FindControl("ddlForEdit");
roleName = DataBinder.Eval(myGridItem.DataItem, "drpColumn").ToString();
editor.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ddlElements));
editor.DataBind();
selectedItem = combo.FindItemByText(roleName);
editor.SelectedIndex = selectedItem.Index;        
    }
}
```

Or you can also try using the template column for making the dropdown list in your grid.

> **UPDATE :**

Try the template column **Method 2**, please remove the code which you already used.
The code which is written in the `ItemDataBound` event will be for edit mode. It will display the dropdownlist only at the time when a user clicks on the edit button.

In Normal mode(Non-Editable grid) by default, either you need to have a value for that particular column or it should be simply left blank. If you have a value from database then you can bind it using `DataBinder.Eval`, so when in normal mode it will display the data from db and in edit mode, it will bind the enum values given from the `ItemDataBound` event.

Comment: Thanks, pasted into VS and got one error: editMan is not declared... - can you help?

Comment: Yes, I am going with second method, tweaking code behind, so thanks for an update.

Comment: Yes there is... grid["drpColumn"] doesn't work :( Says it cannot apply indexing to RadGrid.

Comment: Also IsInEditMode returns false for row I try to edit... There is even question for that on SO - no answer though..

Comment: related and not answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132839/how-to-fill-dropdown-in-telerik-grid-databound